# Jetpack compose bottom sheet drawer opens on its own

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following compose component:

```
@Composable
fun ProductDetails(viewModel: ProductDetailsViewModel) {
    val productInstalmentsByOcrName by viewModel.productInstalmentsByOcrName.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val product by viewModel.product.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val drawerState = rememberBottomDrawerState(BottomDrawerValue.Closed)

    BottomDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            ReportModalContent(ocrProductNames = productInstalmentsByOcrName?.map { it.first }
                ?: emptyList(), onReport = { ocrProductName ->
                viewModel.onReport(ocrProductName)
                scope.launch {
                    drawerState.close()
                }
            })
        },
    ) {

// .... The rest of the code...

          IconButton(
                    onClick = { scope.launch { drawerState.open() } },
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                ) {
// ... The rest of the code
```

This composable represents a screen in my app. When I navigate to it, in the first render of the Composable, the drawer is closed, with `drawerState.isOpen == false`. But immediately after, without the user pressing on the button that should open the drawer, the Composable re-renders and the drawer opens on its own.

At no other point do I access `drawerState` in this code.

I assumed it had something to do with the Navigation component, since this component represents a screen, but not the initial one. But even when rendering as initial destination, the drawer opens on its own.

The first destination screen also has a BottomDrawer that looks just like this, so I thought that might somehow interfere. But after commenting the code from the other component regarding, the bottom sheet the problem still persisted.

Since the other component has an identical looking BottomDrawer, I don't know what the problem with this one is.

How can I fix this?

Here is the navigation composable. The product list is just a list of cells, when tapping on one it navigates to the product details composable. The authentication screen is not relevant for my problem.
When I test for this problem, I am already logged in, so I don't interact with the AuthScreen

#### File *NavigationComposable.kt*

```
fun Navigation(viewModel: NavigationViewModel = koinViewModel()) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val startDestination by viewModel.startRoute.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination) {
        composable(Routes.AUTH) {
            AuthScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(Routes.PRODUCT_LIST) {
            ProductList(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(
            Routes.PRODUCT_DETAILS,
            arguments = listOf(navArgument(Routes.PRODUCT_ID_ARG) { type = NavType.IntType })
        )
        {
            val productId = it.arguments?.getInt(Routes.PRODUCT_ID_ARG)
            ProductDetails(viewModel = getViewModel { parametersOf(productId) })
        }
    }
}
```

#### File *NavigationViewModel.kt*

```
class NavigationViewModel(authRepository: AuthRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val startRoute =authRepository.isLoggedIn.map {
        if (it) Routes.PRODUCT_LIST else Routes.AUTH
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, Routes.AUTH)
}
```

Comment: >  as soon as the component gets rendered, it rerenders and sets the drawerState to Opened.   ------------ how is your viewModel argument being passed? Can you debug and ensure that it's the same instance on the first render and second render?

Comment: I am pretty sure it's the same instance of viewModel because i had a breakpoint in its init block and it was reached only once. But I will double check

Comment: @beyondtheteal I checked. The viewmodel is created only once

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you set `drawerState.open()` but never set `drawerState.close()`, correct?

So it is normal for the drawer to open randomly when the component is recreated for any variation of the data because at that moment it is set to open.

Comment: @G.Ciardini Ok, I guess I stated it wrong. I will update the post. My problem is that when the composable renders the first time, the drawer is closed, but then immediately rerenders and opens the drawers, without me pressing the UI button that opens the drawer

Comment: @AdrianPascu are you sure you haven't use `LaunchEffect()` or `sideEffect()` for opening state right ?

Comment: @PratikFagadiya Yes I am sure. The code snippet I included are the only places the drawerState is used

Comment: @AdrianPascu Quite interesting, cause when i used same code It works fine

Comment: @PratikFagadiya Have you included it in a navigation component as well?

Comment: I still have a gut feeling it is related to the navigation, even though when I used it as the initial destination it stil didn't work correctly

Comment: actually I tried in this composable function direct (Without navigation component and without viewmodel)

Comment: @AdrianPascu can u add code with navigation component ? or provide git repo

Comment: @PratikFagadiyaI have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Reading on GitHub, I came across [this](https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/910#issuecomment-1042946242).

It seems if the content of the BottomDrawer is null (and initially for me it was) or otherwise unpositioned, the BottomDrawer experiences the issue I describe where it opens on its own.